Proving the existence of the limit of the sequence given that the distance between the terms gets smaller
I have to prove that $\lim_{n\to\infty}x_n$ exists given $|x_{n+1}-x_n| = 2^{-n}$
I have proven this using Cauchy criterion: $\forall\epsilon>0 \space \exists N\in\mathbb{N} \space \forall m>n>N:$ $|x_m-x_n| < \epsilon$
However, the task has the following hints:

Use telescoping series
Use comparison test for positive coefficients
Absolute convergence implies convergence

What that other approach might be?
Some facts that might be helpful:$$0\leq\sum_{k=1}^n|x_{n+1}-x_n|<\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{2^k}<\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2^k}=1$$

$$\sum_{n=N}^{\infty} -2^{-n} \leq \sum_{n=N}^{\infty} (x_{n+1} - x_n) \leq \sum_{n=N}^{\infty} 2^{-n} $$  Just incrementing $N$ by one constraints $x_\infty - x_{N+1}$ to half the range $x_\infty - x_{N}$ had.  So you can get the width of that range less than any choice of $\varepsilon$ in the Cauchy criterion by allowing $N$ greater than something like $-\log_2(\varepsilon)$ (probably $\mathrm{max}$-ed with something like $1$).
